# I want to make interpolated heatmap with data from excel

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, interpolation, heatmap

I want to create a heat map similar to the picture below using data from an excel sheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXg5r.png)

I tried to use this code below but swap the np.random.seed for data from the excel but it doesnt work. The excel consists of 2 columns and 4 rows of data.
someone please help. Im new to coding and this is super frustrating.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

methods = [None, 'none', 'sinc']

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

grid = np.random.rand(4, 4)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=6, figsize=(9, 6),
                        subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})

for ax, interp_method in zip(axs.flat, methods):
    ax.imshow(grid, interpolation=interp_method, cmap='viridis')
    ax.set_title(str(interp_method))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by *"it doesn't work"*?  What doesn't work? What is different from what you expected? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.